# How to upgrade ArangoDB on Arch Linux?

Tags: upgrade, arangodb, archlinux

I had ArangoDB 3.3.19 installed on Arch Linux. I noticed that the version in AUR was updated to 3.4, so I did this upgrade:

```
yay -S arangodb
```

However, when I started arangod after the upgrade I received this message:

```
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] ERROR {startup} Database directory version (30319) is lower than current version (30400).
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] ERROR {startup} ----------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] ERROR {startup} It seems like you have upgraded the ArangoDB binary.
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] ERROR {startup} If this is what you wanted to do, please restart with the'
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] ERROR {startup}   --database.auto-upgrade true'
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] ERROR {startup} option to upgrade the data in the database directory.'
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] ERROR {startup} Normally you can use the control script to upgrade your database'
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] ERROR {startup}   /etc/init.d/arangodb stop'
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] ERROR {startup}   /etc/init.d/arangodb upgrade'
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] ERROR {startup}   /etc/init.d/arangodb start'
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] ERROR {startup} ----------------------------------------------------------------------'
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] ERROR Database 'AirlineCompany' needs upgrade. Please start the server with --database.auto-upgrade
2018-12-22T01:25:22Z [2023] FATAL Database 'AirlineCompany' upgrade failed (bad parameter). Please inspect the logs from the upgrade procedure and try starting the server again.
```

The control script `/etc/init.d/arangodb` does not exist on Arch Linux. Is it possible or recommended to upgrade ArangoDB using the control script method? If yes, how is it done?

Or is the best method to do two steps like this?

```
yay -S arangodb
sudo /usr/bin/arangod --database.auto-upgrade true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to refer to the official docs:

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/operations/upgrading/